# http basic authentication testing in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara

I'm trying to test logging in via http basic but am continually getting errors, I've uploaded the code [here](https://github.com/TheBatman/http-basic-test)

I have `http_basic_authenticate_with name: "name", password: "password"`
in my application controller

My step definition for logging in is;

```
Given /^I login as admin$/ do
  authorize "name", "password"
end
```

but it doesn't work and I get the error

```
    expected there to be content "Posts" in "HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n"
 (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

can someone tell me how to get cucumber/capybara to log in?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with one of two different approaches; take your pick:

```
### Following works ONLY if performed first before even going to a page!!!
if page.driver.respond_to?(:basic_auth)
  puts 'Responds to basic_auth'
  page.driver.basic_auth(username, password)
elsif page.driver.respond_to?(:basic_authorize)
  puts 'Responds to basic_authorize'
  page.driver.basic_authorize(username, password)
elsif page.driver.respond_to?(:browser) && page.driver.browser.respond_to?(:basic_authorize)
  puts 'Responds to browser_basic_authorize'
  page.driver.browser.basic_authorize(username, password)
else
  raise "I don't know how to log in!"
end
```

My tests responded to browser_basic_authorize

or

```
encoded_login = ["#{username}:#{password}"].pack("m*")
page.driver.header 'Authorization', "Basic #{encoded_login}"
```

both of which I found at several places in my search.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selenium web driver and visit the website with page.driver.visit("https://username:password@example.com")